# Selecting an interval on the Y-Axis in Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

In the `YAxis` I require it to be 0 1000 2000 3000, requiring an interval of 1000 but what I get is 0 2500 5000 7500 10000
Please let me know how to set the interval

```
data = [
  {
    "name": "Jan 2021",
    "Product A": 3432,
    "Procuct B": 2342
  },
  {
    "name": "Feb 2021",
    "Product A": 2342,
    "Procuct B": 3246
  },
  {
    "name": "Mar 2021",
    "Product A": 4565,
    "Procuct B": 4556
  },
  {
    "name": "Apr 2021",
    "Product A": 6654,
    "Procuct B": 4465
  },
  {
    "name": "May 2021",
    "Product A": 8765,
    "Procuct B": 4553
  }
];

render() {
  return (
    <LineChart width={730} height={250} data={this.data}>
      {/* <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" /> */}
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee" strokeDasharray="5 5"/>

      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 10000]}/>
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Product A" stroke="#0095FF" />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Procuct B" stroke="#FF0000" />
    </LineChart>
  );
};
```

Thanks for the help

Output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On an axis, there are 5 ticks by default.

In order to display all the thousands ticks (1000, 2000, etc.), you need to set the `tickCount` on your `YAxis` to `11`, like the following:

```
<YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 10000]} tickCount={11} />
```

But you'll also need to make the chart's height bigger, otherwise all the ticks cannot be displaied properly. To do that, you could just update the `height` prop in the `LineChart` component:

```
<LineChart width={730} height={500} data={data}> // <-- just here
  <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee" strokeDasharray="5 5"/>
  <YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 10000]} tickCount={11}/>
  <Tooltip />
  <Legend />
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Product A" stroke="#0095FF" />
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Procuct B" stroke="#FF0000" />
</LineChart>
```

Which would result like the image below:
[image]

Comment: Note that you may also need to provide an interval for the `YAxis` to get this to display properly; e.g., `<YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 10000]} tickCount={11} interval={1000} />`.